# Decrypt an OpenEdge-encrypted String (AES-128) in PHP

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, aes, openedge

This is the function I use in OpenEdge 10.1B to encrypt a string with AES-128 OFB:

```
 DEFINE VAR cRes AS CHAR INITIAL ? NO-UNDO.
 DEFINE VAR rKey AS RAW NO-UNDO.
 DEFINE VAR rEnc AS RAW NO-UNDO

 rKey = GENERATE-PBE-KEY(cEncKey).

 eEnc = ENCRYPT(cData, rKey, ?, "AES_OFB_128").
 cRes = BASE64-ENCODE(rEnc) NO-ERROR.

 IF ERROR-STATUS::ERROR THEN cRes = ?.

 return cRes.
```

This function does encrypt well.

When I want to decrypt this with the following PHP, it fails, e.g. it gives me a different result than the original string.

```
// decrypted: original string is supposed to have 33 characters
$encrypted = "YnRvNjIG1kj1QtUM9ZYuVYS3D4LBYCEsprjg2QCaD/eM";
$key = "27Zkp6Wq";

$method = 'aes-128-ofb';

# do decryption
echo "<pre>".openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($encrypted), $method, $key, false)."</pre>";
```

I understand that might have something to do with the GENERATE-PBE-KEY function, but I fail to see how I can generate an PCKS#5 key in PHP.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Shouldn't the method read `AES-128-OFB` in the PHP ?

Comment: Also, you should make sure you are setting a consistent character encoding in OpenEdge and PHP

Comment: aes-128-ofb is acceptable (see http://php.net/manual/de/function.openssl-get-cipher-methods.php) - but just for the sake of it - the result is the exact same to the UPPERCASE version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was too long for a comment. A few things to look at:

1. The fourth parameter of `openssl_decrypt` should be `true` OR the first parameter should be left base64 encoded. Unless it was double base64 encoded :)
2. Is the key base64 encoded or is that the raw key?
3. From the OpenEdge it's not entirely clear whether `PBES1 (pbkdf1)` or `PBES2 (pbkdf2)` is applied to the key, but the default settings use `sha1` as the hash algorithm, no salt and `1000` as the iteration count. You can find example PHP implementations online.

Having fiddled with your example I couldn't get it to work, but the above should lead you in the right direction; btw, when I tried doing the encoding step in PHP it resulted in a much shorter encrypted string ... I'm not sure what to think of that :)

Comment: Accepted this answer because it gave me a new approach. See my answer to my own question to see how I solved this in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have SECURITY-POLICY:PBE-HASH-ALGORITHM and SECURITY-POLICY:PBE-KEY-ROUNDS defined anywhere?:

http://documentation.progress.com/output/OpenEdge102b/pdfs/dvpin/dvpin.pdf#page=173

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I finally gave up. The problem obviously was the hash function in OpenEdge which I failed to reproduce in PHP. The solution was to get the hashed key from the hash function and move it in HEX to the PHP over a second channel, to use it there to decrypt.

It's not perfectly secure, it's not elegant, but it works, and our security problems are not code-side, but database storage side. Your requirements might be different, so use this approach only if you are certain it will be useable.

Answer (score 0):

In OpenEdge code you should change:

```
rKey = GENERATE-PBE-KEY(cEncKey)
```

to:

```
rKey = MESSAGE-DIGEST('SHA-256', cEncKey)
```

And in PHP code you should use:

```php
$key = substr(hash('sha256', $cEncKey, true), 0, 32);
```

And you will get it working.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).